# How to use Qt inner process communication to return value to native win32 application (and not using tcp)

Tags: winapi, qt

I have native win32 application that starts Qt exe application with (probably ) CreateProcess function 
The Qt application doing some work , now when the Qt application done its job I need it somehow to signal back with returned parameter 
String type . what is the best way to implement such thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution is to trivial for you but here it is anyway:

a) let the Qt application write something on stdout, the calling win32 application should be able to read it and parse it.

b) You could for a brief moment use the windows clipboard [QClipboard](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qclipboard.html)

c) You could write a temporary file containing the string.

Best regards
D

Comment: i want to avoid the file solution , how can i read the Qt stdout?

Comment: From the native win32 application the created Qt application is just another process. During the creation of the new app (`CreateProcess()`) you vould specify the `hStdOutput` HANDLE of the `STARTUPINFO` struct used in `CreateProcess()` in order to read the stdout of the Qt application.

Comment: so if i understand you right , i have to open in Qt application another cmd window?

Comment: No. You have a native win32 application that starts a Qt application. And you want the Qt application to send a string to this native one but without IPC or a temporary file. The Qt application simply opens a `QTextStream` for example which is initialized with `stoud` and writes the string to that. The actual work has to be done on the side of the native win32 application which has to read the stdout of your Qt application.

Comment: so if i understand you right , i simple do somthing like : QTextStream stream(stout); stream << "some_value" ; and then in the win32 app i just invoke the CreateProcess with hStdOutput HANDLE of the STARTUPINFO?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I do not know how to read the stdout from the HANDLE in the win32 application without looking at the msdn but I'm sure it has been asked allready.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use stdout to communicate this. When you call the process create a file in a temporary location and pass its handle to the new process as stdout. Then wait on the newly created process handle. Once the process finishes read the information out of the file.